# How to filter (key, value) with ng-repeat in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frameworks, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I am trying to do something like :

```
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="(k,v) in items | filter:hasSecurityId">
        {{k}} {{v.pos}}
    </div>
</div>
```

AngularJs Part:

```
function TestCtrl($scope) 
{
    $scope.items = {
                     'A2F0C7':{'secId':'12345', 'pos':'a20'},
                     'C8B3D1':{'pos':'b10'}
                   };

    $scope.hasSecurityId = function(k,v)
    {
       return v.hasOwnProperty('secId');
    }
}
```

But somehow, it is showing me all items. How can I filter on (key,value) ?

Comment: please provide some example data fot items. Or give us a fiddle ;)

Comment: This is not how you create a filter look at the [documentations](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.templates.filters.creating_filters), and as Robin said, an example please.

Comment: I already gave a full example and I know how to use filters. I am just asking "how to use filter with (key,value)".

Comment: index and count should be available in that scope iirc

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Angular [filters](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter) can only be applied to arrays and not objects, from angular's API -

> "Selects a subset of items from array and returns it as a new array."

You have two options here:
1) move `$scope.items` to an array or -
2) pre-filter the `ng-repeat` items, like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="(k,v) in filterSecId(items)">
    {{k}} {{v.pos}}
</div>
```

And on the Controller:

```
$scope.filterSecId = function(items) {
    var result = {};
    angular.forEach(items, function(value, key) {
        if (!value.hasOwnProperty('secId')) {
            result[key] = value;
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

**jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/bmleite/WA2BE/

Comment: One needs to be careful with this approach to avoid infinite (digest) loops. See [6054](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6054) and [705](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/705). Summary by [Narretz](https://github.com/Narretz): _In short, using functions to return the collection in ng-repeat is an anti-pattern. It's better to assign the collection to a scope property, and loop over that._

Comment: Helpful comment. This was throwing me for a loop; I expected to be able to filter *any* iterable. Thanks much. :)

Comment: Note: This is a perf anti-pattern now. Angular 1.3 has stateless filters now (https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-new-in-angular-1-3-stateless-filters) so you'd definitely want to create a filter for this.

Comment: @kentcdodds don't post links which are not free!

Comment: @Sebastian, sorry about that. But there are people who are egghead.io subscribers and I expect it's useful to them.

Comment: Why not just add an ng-if on the repeated element?

Answer (score 46):

My solution would be create custom filter and use it:

```
app.filter('with', function() {
  return function(items, field) {
        var result = {};
        angular.forEach(items, function(value, key) {
            if (!value.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
                result[key] = value;
            }
        });
        return result;
    };
});
```

And in html:

```
 <div ng-repeat="(k,v) in items | with:'secId'">
        {{k}} {{v.pos}}
 </div>
```

Comment: however, it will loop n*n times.

Answer (score 34):

Also you can use `ng-repeat` with `ng-if`:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in order" ng-if="value > 0">
```

Comment: Clever. This saved a lot of time.

Answer (score 21):

Or simply use

```
ng-show="v.hasOwnProperty('secId')"
```

See updated solution here:

http://jsfiddle.net/RFontana/WA2BE/93/

Comment: Thanks.. I used this but with `ng-if` instead

Answer (score 11):

You can simply use [angular.filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) module, and then you can filter even by nested properties.
see: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/royuj/10/edit?html,js,output)
**2 Examples:**

**JS:**

```
angular.module('app', ['angular.filter'])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  //your example data
  $scope.items = { 
    'A2F0C7':{ secId:'12345', pos:'a20' },
    'C8B3D1':{ pos:'b10' }
  };
  //more advantage example
  $scope.nestedItems = { 
    'A2F0C7':{
      details: { secId:'12345', pos:'a20' }
    },
    'C8B3D1':{
      details: { pos:'a20' }
    },
    'F5B3R1': { secId:'12345', pos:'a20' }
  };
});
```

**HTML:**

```
  <b>Example1:</b>
  <p ng-repeat="item in items | toArray: true | pick: 'secId'">
    {{ item.$key }}, {{ item }}
  </p>

  <b>Example2:</b>
  <p ng-repeat="item in nestedItems | toArray: true | pick: 'secId || details.secId' ">
    {{ item.$key }}, {{ item }}
  </p>
```

Comment: You should disclose that `angular.filter` is not a core angular module and you are the author of it.

Comment: It looks like the `toArray` filter is not present anymore. Is there a replacement, because the `filter` filter still does not allow objects?

Answer (score 7):

It is kind of late, but I looked for e similar filter and ended using something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
 <div ng-repeat="(k,v) in items | filter:{secId: '!!'}">
   {{k}} {{v.pos}}
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How did you get this to work? When I use a filter with an ng-repeated object, I get an error which is what is expected base on the Angular documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is rather old, I'd like to share my solution for angular 1 developers. The point is to just reuse the original angular filter, but transparently passing any objects as an array.

```
app.filter('objectFilter', function ($filter) {
    return function (items, searchToken) {
        // use the original input
        var subject = items;

        if (typeof(items) == 'object' && !Array.isArray(items)) {
            // or use a wrapper array, if we have an object
            subject = [];

            for (var i in items) {
                subject.push(items[i]);
            }
        }

        // finally, apply the original angular filter
        return $filter('filter')(subject, searchToken);
    }
});
```

use it like this:

```
<div>
    <input ng-model="search" />
</div>
<div ng-repeat="item in test | objectFilter : search">
    {{item | json}}
</div>
```

here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/oQkxzx8sNp93pHCWadHR?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I made a bit more of a generic filter that I've used in multiple projects already:

- object = the object that needs to be filtered
- field = the field within that object that we'll filter on
- filter = the value of the filter that needs to match the field

**HTML:**

```
<input ng-model="customerNameFilter" />
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in filter(customers, 'customerName', customerNameFilter" >
   <p>Number: {{value.customerNo}}</p>
   <p>Name: {{value.customerName}}</p>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
  $scope.filter = function(object, field, filter) {
    if (!object) return {};
    if (!filter) return object;

    var filteredObject = {};
    Object.keys(object).forEach(function(key) {
      if (object[key][field] === filter) {
        filteredObject[key] = object[key];
      }
    });

    return filteredObject;
  };
```