# Angular ng-class if length of array is less than X?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to conditionally add two classes using ng-class.

I want to add class `checked` if `case` has commments, and I want to add class `lots` if the length of the comments array is more than 10.

This works, to add `checked` if case has comments:

```
<p class="comments" ng-class="{checked: case.comments}">
```

But this doesn't work- it doesn't give me `checked` OR `lots`:

```
<p class="comments" ng-class="{checked: case.comments, lots: case.comments.length >= 10}">
```

Should I skip trying to do this in the HTML & calculate it on a $scope boolean instead, or is there a way to do this in the HTML?

UPDATE:
Never mind, the error was in my observational skills, not the code. It works in its given form, but I was looking for the result in the wrong place. D'oh.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529825/angularjs-ngclass-conditional

Comment: @apohl I think this is a different question.

Comment: Thats... strange. It is written correctly as far as I can see. Have you tried printing out the length below, just {{case.comments.length}} in the html, just to check that nothing strange is going on when getting .length?

Answer (score 0):

why you don't add a function to to manage this, something like

Here is a [plunker sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/JnYU3X6YA9aTgGKJLJEB?p=preview)

**controller**

```
$scope.hasComments = function(case){
   var commentsCode = 0;
   if (case.comments){
      commentsCode = 1;
   }
   if (case.comments.length >= 10){
      commentsCode = 2
   }

    return commentsCode ;
}
```

**html**

```
<p class="comments" ng-class="{1: 'checked', 2: 'checked lots'}[hasComments(case)]">
```