# Dynamically showing/hiding slides from ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

With angular, I'm creating a slide show dynamically with 50+ slides in it. Now this effects the browser and slows a lot of things down. So I added an `ng-class` the slides to evaluate their index.

```
ng-class="currentSlide >= (currentSlide-1) && currentSlide <= (currentSlide+1) ? 'visible' : 'hidden'"
```

`currentSlide` is a variable that will return the current index of the slide when ever the slide chagnes, so it will always update.

I know `currentSlide` works, whats wrong is my `ng-class` expression.
Is it possible to do the math, even if it is as simple as `+ 1`, inside of the expression?

Or should I more this out to variables in my controller and get their value there?

Comment: You shouldn't be coding in your view, it goes against the MVVM approach. The correct approach is move this operation to your controller or custom filter

Comment: Works for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/Pcm9O0Awcv1fiELLcdB3?p=preview Are you using an old version of Angular (< 1.1.5)?

Comment: So, you aren't seeing `visible` or `hidden` classes added to your element?

Comment: Visible is being added, but not hidden when the slides are changed. But if I use static conditionals, `<= 1 ` etc, things works

Comment: It seems that it would make sense that `"currentSlide >= (currentSlide-1) && currentSlide <= (currentSlide+1)"` would always evaluate to truthy, though, right? ... no matter what integer value `currentSlide` is ... (e.g. `(-1 >= -2) && (-1 <= 0) == true`, `(1 >= 0) && (1 <= 2) == true`)

Comment: Ah I see now, since they're dynamic thats how they will behave...damn.
See I started off doing this with the static ng-classes and wanted to to move it into dynamically filtering to make less work

Comment: So the main purpose of this is to only be able to keep three slides visible at a time, the previous slide, current, and next slide.

Here's a codepen
http://codepen.io/mhartington/pen/kFhAp

Comment: I think we're starting to stray far from the original question. Maybe you should ask a new question or else feel free to contact me privately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My ng-class wasn't working because I was getting the index according to the slide, not the ng-repeat.

```
 ng-show="$index >= (currentSlide-1) && $index <= (currentSlide+1)"
```

Using `$index` solved my problem. Thanks for the help all!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ng-class="{ 'visible': currentSlide >= (currentSlide-1) && currentSlide <= (currentSlide+1) }"
```

Related: [AngularJS ngClass conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529825/angularjs-ngclass-conditional)

The ng-class conditional syntax doesn't seem to be written anywhere obvious.

Comment: Seems to be the same expression as above but with out the conditional classes that I need. Plus when I used it in my example, the classes didn't update.

Comment: you can add more by adding `,` between them. Also is currentSlide on the scope?