# Add/Toggle CSS with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

So basically I have a control on my page which when clicked needs to toggle two different elements with two different CSS classes.

I have managed to get it to toggle one of the controls, but not both.

**Here is my element:**

This is the element that needs to trigger both controls.

```
<a id="main-menu-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sidebar" class="hidden-xs open"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
```

**The first element (That is working):**

```
<div id="sidebar" class="col-lg-2 col-sm-1 collapse" style="min-height: 759px; display: block;">

</div>
```

**Here is the second element(That i need to add):**

For this element i need to trigger the CSS class 'full' when the button is clicked and then not full when its clicked again.

```
<div id="content" class="col-lg-10 col-sm-11 full">

</div>
```

I have tried to do this to the hyperlink control and it still doesn't work:

```
<a id="main-menu-toggle" data-toggle="collapse,full" data-target="#sidebar,#content" class="hidden-xs open"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
```

Does anyone know how I can get this working using AngularJS?

Answer (score 3):

Try using "**ng-class**".

Reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16529903/5052704

Hope this helps.

Comment: I will take a look now as it seems to be the same sort of thing. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/smebrtwt/1) usign `ng-class` and `ng-click`:

```
<a id="main-menu-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sidebar" class="hidden-xs open" ng-click="clicked = (clicked) ? false : true">
   <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>click
</a>

<div id="sidebar" class="col-lg-2 col-sm-1 collapse" ng-class="{'full': clicked}" style="min-height: 759px; display: block;">
   THEDIV
 </div>
```

Comment: Nothing happens on the fiddle when i click?

Comment: Inspect the element you will see it adds and removes the `full` class EDIT: Added color to class to show something http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/smebrtwt/1/

Comment: Yeah it shows and hides the red box, but i want it to do two different things at the same time.

Comment: "when clicked needs to toggle two different elements with two different CSS classes."

Comment: Still not clear, but try this: http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/smebrtwt/2/ or explain better your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) for class and [ngStyle](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) for style manipulation.