# How to use AngularJS ng-Class condition based on another element's class?

Tags: angularjs

```
<div id="parent" ng-class="{testClass:???}">
   <span id="child" class="test"/>
</div>
```

On this example, how would I do it so that if element child would have a class `test`, the parent element would dynamically have the class `testClass`?

Comment: Do you control the class of the child? I mean its obviously dynamic in some form but if its not set with `ng-class` how is it set?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS ngClass conditional](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529825/angularjs-ngclass-conditional)

Answer (score 3):

You can create a scope variable to validate whether those 2 elements should be visible or not. 
The inner span too should be getting set dynamically according to your description. So you can use ng-class for that too.
So the code can be like this :

```
<div id="parent" ng-class="{testClass : isValid}">
    <span id="child" ng-class="{test : isValid}"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add the ternary condition within the ng-class like

```
var var-test = 'hi'=='bye'
ng-class=" var-test ? 'class-if-true' : 'class-if-false'">
```

and put in your css file the classes

```
.class-if-true{color=black}
.class-if-false{color=white}
```