# Angular set :active selector of CSS by ng class

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I would like to set the className:active selector by ng-class like so:
`ng-class='{"className:active" : true}'`

Comment: Don't think that you can/may do that. Please explain your use case, why would you want to do that? You could set the `.focus()`, then it would be the active element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have to "fake" it by creating class that has exactly the same properties as your :active pseudo class.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
ng-class="{'active':true}"
```

for variable you can try

```
<!-- add a class to the first item -->
<ul>
    <li ng-class="{ 'text-success': $first }" ng-repeat="item in items">{{ item.name }}</li>
</ul>

<!-- add a class to the last item -->
<ul>
    <li ng-class="{ 'text-danger': $last }" ng-repeat="item in items">{{ item.name }}</li>
</ul>

<!-- add a class to the even items and a different class to the odd items -->
<ul>
    <li ng-class="{ 'text-info': $even, 'text-danger': $odd }" ng-repeat="item in items">{{ item.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

[for more options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529825/angularjs-ngclass-conditional)

Comment: Doest seem to set the :active selector on my class