# Conditionally apply boot strap columns with ng-class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to use `col-sm-9` when a flag is set to false, and `col-sm-5` when it is set to true. I'm trying this

```
<div ng-class="{col-sm-9: !flag, col-sm-5: flag" class="col-sm-offset-3}"></div>
```

I get a `$parse:syntax` error at the first hyphen after the `{`. I've tried putting single quotes around the class names as well and continued to get syntax errors. What am I doing wrong? Also, is it ok if I try to apply that additional class at the end no matter what because they both need applied on the same div?

Edit: syntax from me typing this this morning

Comment: try quotes: `'col-sm-9'` (as a class name, and not a scoped variable). Also missing `}` at the end, and should be `</div>` instead of `<\div>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529825/angularjs-ngclass-conditional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:-

```
  <div ng-class="{'col-sm-9': !flag, 'col-sm-5': flag}" class="col-sm-offset-3"><\div>
```