# Applying classes in Angular templates

Tags: angular, angular-template

I'm using the `[class.*]` syntax to apply classes conditionally.
I've found myself wanting to always apply a class.

My current code is as follow:

```
[class.general]="true"
[class.new]="model.isNew"
[class.edited]="model.isEdited"
```

The `[class.general]="true"` is a bit weird and feels like an hack. Is there  a standard/better way to have a fixed class while also using conditionals for other classes?

Comment: `class="general" [class.new]="model.isNew" ...`

Comment: @yurzui really? I feel dumb. I tought it would get overridden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding to the @yurzui point, If you have multiple classes adding dynamically, I would suggest using `ngClass`

```
<div class="general" [ngClass]="{'new': model.isNew, 'edited': model.isEdited}">
```

Comment: I've considered it, but being a matter of taste, I prefer the `[class]` way. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can try following ways of assigning class

- Try ngClass from [Official Documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)
- If you want to use some conditional way to apply classes, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529825/angularjs-ngclass-conditional)