# Multiple condition on ng-class in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

how can I add extra condition on below code

```
<div ng-class="{true: 'complete'}[item.Id != 0]"></div>
```

here I need to add  `"{true: 'abc'}[item.name == "FName"]`, can anyone help me out.

thank you

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? what is that condition suppose to mean?

Comment: i just wanted to add extra condition.

Comment: `true: 'abc'` is not a condition... `ng-class=" (item.id != 0 && /* some other condition*/) ? 'classNameWhenConditionsMet' : 'classNameWhenConditionsAreNotMet'"` is what you are looking for ?

Comment: I need to add two different classes based on the condtions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you want `complete` class to be added with this condition: `item.Id != 0`. The correct syntax for this is the below:

```
<div ng-class="{ 'complete': item.Id != 0 }"></div>
```

You can add as many classes you want using a comma:

```
<div ng-class="{ 'complete': item.Id != 0, 'abc': item.name == 'FName' }"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

After doing a quick search i found this:

```
ng-class="{'test': obj.value1 == 'someothervalue' || obj.value2 == 'somethingelse'}"
```

Source: [AngularJS ngClass conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529825/angularjs-ngclass-conditional)
Credits go to https://stackoverflow.com/users/736482/bertrand

Comment: I need to add two different classes based on the condtions

Comment: So you need something like if condition : class elseif condition:class else nothing ?

Comment: No, both condtion should work, as shown below

```<div ng-class="{true: 'complete'}[item.Id != 0],{true: 'abc'}[item.name == "FName"]"></div>```

here abc is class, but here second condition is not working

Comment: I have no ideea of your conditions but what I have noticed is that you double quoted Fname which will break your code:
<div ng-class="{true: 'complete'}[item.Id != 0],{true: 'abc'}[item.name == 'FName']"></div>