# AngularJS conditional styling

Tags: html, angularjs

can someone please provide me with the correct AngularJS syntax to swap this one to ng-class:

```
<div class="visible-md pull-left">
...
</div>
```

(= if screen size is medium, pull the content of the div to left)

Please note that [I have seen this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529825/angularjs-ngclass-conditional) and went through all the examples but none seemed to the do trick.

```
<div ng-class="{???}">
...
</div>
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: `None of them seemed to do the trick` is a hard pill to swallow when that is an exact dupe of this question. Maybe post what you tried that didn't seem "to do the trick"?

Comment: Maybe take a look at this [codepen](https://codepen.io/DevelopIntelligenceBoulder/pen/rewObY/)?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to use ng-class for pulling the content of the div to the left if size is medium. If you can use Bootstrap 4, check out responsive floats:

```html
<div class="float-sm-left">Float left on viewports sized SM (small) or wider</div><br>
<div class="float-md-left">Float left on viewports sized MD (medium) or wider</div><br>
<div class="float-lg-left">Float left on viewports sized LG (large) or wider</div><br>
<div class="float-xl-left">Float left on viewports sized XL (extra-large) or wider</div><br>
```

If you have to use Bootstrap 3, you could create your own "responsive pull" css class:

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .pull-left-md {
        float: left;
    }
}
```