# angularjs + how to apply css class to message text, based on http post response

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I would like to be able to add a CSS class to the text color of a message based on the response.

Currently I do it this method:

```
if (response.data.status == 201) {
    angular.element(document.getElementById("msg")).css("color", "green");
    $scope.msg = 'Users created for Meeting ' + r.id
        + ' on ' + $filter('date')(r.updated_at, 'M/d/yyyy')
        + ' at ' + $filter('date')(r.updated_at, 'HH:mm:ss');
    console.log("Status Code= " + response.data.status + ", Status Text= " + response.data.message);
    return true;
}
else {
    angular.element(document.getElementById("msg")).css("color", "red");
    $scope.msg = r.message;
    angular.element("#meeting-id").focus()
    console.log("Status Code= " + response.data.status + ", Status Text= " + response.data.message);
    
    return false;
}
```

and it works, but now I have two classes that can be added to the success and error messages.
I need to figure out how to add them so that I can remove the style attribute that changes the text to red or green.

The classes names are:

```
•   Success: “text-green”

•   Error: “text-red”
```

What is the method to correctly achieve this?

Any help would be great.

Thank you,
Erasmo

Comment: You can use ngClass to provide the element with classes on the go. This should resolve your issue: https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Comment: How would using ngClass look within the existent code? Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AngularJS ngClass conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529825/angularjs-ngclass-conditional)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ng-class for this
in js file

```
      $scope.responseCode = response.data.status;
```

then  in html

```
    <div ng-class="{'text-success':responseCode == 201,'text-danger':responseCode != 201}">
        <h1>Welcome Home!</h1>
        <p>I like it!</p>
    </div>
```

Refer this more about ng-class: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

or Using classList.add:

For success message you can use

```
     angular.element(document.getElementById("msg")).classList.add('green');
```

For Error message you can use

```
angular.element(document.getElementById("msg")).classList.add('red');
```

Comment: I am not sure how to implement ngClass