# Conditional call of class from <td> tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
<td class="text-center">
```

Is there a way to call a class in the above `<td>` tag based on a condition (Boolean value check)?
I want to add  "pointer"  to the class call if the condition is true and leave it as  "text-center"  if it is false... like below:

if condition is met:

```
<td class="pointer text-center">
```

if condition is not met:

```
<td class="text-center">
```

Comment: Angular: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269179/angular-conditional-class-with-ngclass AngularJS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529825/angularjs-ngclass-conditional This might be work you

Answer (score 0):

What you want is [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

The following example uses a $scope variable `conditionIsMet`

```
<td ng-class="{'pointer': conditionIsMet}" class="text-center">
```