# AngularJS: condition in ng-repeat directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like like to know how can i set a condition in a ng-repeat who is in a directive call:

```
<map-marker ng-repeat='obj in objects'
  title=      'obj.name'
  latitude=   'obj.last_point().latitude'
  longitude=  'obj.last_point().longitude'
  click=      'state.toggle_selected(obj)'
  icon=       'obj.toggle_icon()'>
</map-marker>
```

I would like to set a marker for my map only if the obj has last_point(). kind of:

```
<map-marker ng-repeat='obj in objects' ng-if='obj.last_point()' ...
```

My map-marker is a custom directive.

I can't find a solution. Do you know how I can do that please?

Thanks for help

Comment: may be just use `filter` on your `objects` ?

Comment: i'm trying but I have a collection of objects, but I don't know what to do with it. For the moment I have: `@am.filter "has_point", ->
  (input) ->
    console.log input
` and for my call: `<map-marker ng-repeat='obj in objects | has_point'`. I don't know how to call the technician 't' to the filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about pre-filter the list in order to it?

I found this in the forum, it might help you:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14789258/1683636