# Filter Firebase data using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

i have a data in firebase like this:

```
firebase_data {
    -JGc5X37NDuvmJylmx0s: Object {
        name: 'John Doe',
        age: 21
    }
    -JGnGJlTjyAxFT-Vn48Y: Object {
        name: 'Jane Doe',
        age: 22
    }
}
```

in my controller:

```
$scope.firebase = $firebase(new Firebase("https://firebase_data.firebaseio.com"));
```

my view:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search" />
<ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in firebase | filter:search">  
    <li><a href="{{ key }}">{{ value.name }}</a></li>
</ul>
```

the filter is not working. how can i make the filter work?

Comment: Filters only work on arrays. Have a look at this ['How to filter (key, value) with ng-repeat in AngularJs?'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788652/how-to-filter-key-value-with-ng-repeat-in-angularjs) for workarounds:

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [orderByPriority](https://www.firebase.com/docs/angular/reference.html#ordered-data-and-arrays) to convert your Firebase object to an array.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search" />
<ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in firebase | orderByPriority | filter:search">  
    <li><a href="{{ key }}">{{ value.name }}</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Today, `orderByPriority` is deprecated, right? I've been trying to use this but it's doesn't work.

Comment: In the latest versions just use `$asArray` which already provides sorted values.

Answer (score 2):

I think firebase returns as object and angular's filter will filter only arrays and does not filter object

You can create custom filter and filter. I have created example for that using firebase object

http://plnkr.co/edit/tiSsswXQWgAPPv6ozqOm?p=preview

Please let me know if anything