# AngularJS: Filter on one of multiple unpacked items in a loop

Tags: arrays, angularjs, filter

I have a set of nested JSON objects, all with the same keys, so I'm just taking the first one, and unpacking its values into (key, val) so they can be edited.

```
{ 'tweedle beetle': { action: battle,
                      item: paddle,
                      color: blue },
  'poodle':         { action: eating,
                      item: noodles,
                       color: white },
  'bottle':         { action: sitting,
                      item: poodle,
                      color: transparent },
  'fox':            { action: watching,
                      item: battle,
                      color: red }
}
```

But not all keys are editable.  So I have a list of editable fields:

```
$scope.editableFields = ['item', 'color'];
```

When looping through the first record, I only want the editableFields to show up.  How do I add the "key" item to the filter as the item to be filtered, since I'm unpacking the items into two values?  I only want a list of the keys of any item that are editable.  Maybe there's an even better way to go about this than taking items[0]?

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt ng-repeat-start="(key,val) in items[0] | filter:editableFields">
        {{key}}
    </dt>
    <dd ng-repeat-end>
        <input class="form-control input-md" type="text" value="{{val}}" />
    </dd>
</dl>
```

The purpose of this is a bulk editor.  I have the list of items to be updated with the new values, but I only need to show the user the options once.

Comment: You're not able to do a filter on an object like that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14789258/238427

Answer (score 0):

I agree with JoseM you cannot do that, but here is an analogous example which might be helpful:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, data) in commands | orderObjectBy:'pos'">{{data.pos}} - {{key}}</div>

$scope.commands = {
        "xyz" : {
            "group":"g2",
            "pos":2
        },
        "abc" : {
            "group":"g2",
            "pos":3
        },
        "ijk" : {
            "group":"g1",
            "pos":1
        }
    };

.filter('orderObjectBy', function() {
  return function(items, field, reverse) {
    var filtered = [];
    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
      filtered.push(item);
    });
    filtered.sort(function (a, b) {
      return (a[field] > b[field]);
    });
    if(reverse) filtered.reverse();
    return filtered;
  };
});
```