# How do I use ng-repeat on a JSONObject (not array), and filter by the key?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, angularjs

I've tried looking for other stackOverflow posts, but none were working for me.

I have a JSONObject that resembles this:

```
{QRX23: {element: { ... }  }, RIJ52:  { model: } }
```

It's obviously much bigger, and has more information, but the main point is that each type of object doesn't have identical types of information, so I really cannot use an array or something here.

Now, I am trying to use ng-repeat and go through this object, and while using it i want to use the filter. I have a form inside my HTML document, and I want to filter the form's ng-model value to the current object's KEY (not value) while it is being traversed.

Thanks in advance for the help.

---

EDIT: Just to give more context, while I'm using ng-repeat, I, for example, iterate through each of the main items (such as QRX23) using ng-repeat. Then within this ng-repeat, I have another ng-repeat which should go through the keys within the main items.

Then, I want to filter these keys, and basically check, for example, if the main item has a key in the object called "element", it can be displayed.

---

```
<div  ng-repeat="(observer, observerObj) in JSONbugs | filter:observerSelection" class="row">
    <h5>{{observer}} </h5>
    <div  ng-repeat="(host, hostObj) in observerObj | filter:hostSelection" class="col-md-6" >
        <h6>Host {{host}}</h6>
        <div ng-repeat="(bug, times) in hostObj | filter: bugSelection">{{bug}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to filter (key, value) with ng-repeat in AngularJs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788652/how-to-filter-key-value-with-ng-repeat-in-angularjs)

Comment: I think you are going to need to create a small data set and demo that shows what you are trying to do. You can't bind `ng-model` directly to the main object keys, so it would have to be a property within that key

Comment: I looked at that before, and it didn't seem to work @przno.

For one thing, if I do make a function, how do I pass my ng-model variable (from a text field) to this function so it can check if the key will be equal or not?

Comment: @charlietfl so say I am using ng-repeat like this:

<div ng-repeat="(host, hostObj) in observerObj | filter:hostSelection" class="col-md-6" >

hostSelection is the ng-model variable, and I basically want to filter out the ones where host (the key) is not equal to whatever is typed in the hostSelection text field.

Comment: too much to handle trying to decifer nested `ng-repeats` in comment blocks. Make a simple demo please in http://plnkr.co or jsfiddle.net

Comment: @charlietfl I've added my code above. Don't try to focus on the nested ng-repeats, that's not my problem. My problem is trying to filter out based on the key in the key,value pair.

Comment: 3 custom filters hard to help with.Live demo is best solution

Comment: Would you mind telling me how to do that? I tried using some custom filters a while back, and it didn't work because I wasn't able to use my ng-model value variable to check.

Comment: @charlietfl Still doesn't seem to be working, you know what else I should try?

Comment: I'm sorry but there just isn't enough here for anyone to help without a live demo. I regret I will have to move on from this

Comment: @charlietfl Alright sure, just one quick question, if I was to make a function, do you know how to pass in the ng-model variable?