# Filter an ng-repeat that is displaying an object?

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

When I display an object using ng-repeat, a filter does not work.

If the same object of objects is instead an array of objects, everything works as expected.

Here's a plunker demonstrating http://plnkr.co/edit/hBEk34U9SLlfoI5Lhitq?p=preview

```
Test.controller('TestController', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    1: {value: '1'},
    2: {value: '2'},
    3: {value: '3'},
    4: {value: '1'},
    5: {value: '2'},
    6: {value: '3'},
    7: {value: '1'},
    8: {value: '2'},
    9: {value: '3'}    
  };
  $scope.filters = {}
});

<input type="text" ng-model="filters.value">
<div ng-repeat="(id, thing) in data | filter: filters">{{thing.value}}</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to filter (key, value) with ng-repeat in AngularJs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788652/how-to-filter-key-value-with-ng-repeat-in-angularjs)

Comment: You're absolutely correct.

Answer (score 0):

In case this doesn't get closed, the answer is that you can't use the built in filter on objects. In my case I just did this:

```
<li ng-repeat="product in products | toArray | filter:filters">

# Convert to array
SingularAdmin.filter 'toArray', () ->
    return (items) ->
        if !items
            return []

        filtered = []
        angular.forEach items, (item) ->
            filtered.push(item)

        return filtered
```