# ng-repeat orderBy object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

UPDATE:

on my html page I'm using as the following:

```
<section ng-repeat="template in templates">
        <ng-include src="template"></ng-include>
    </section>
```

but the problem is that I need specific file in certain order so is there a way I can control the way order is rendering?

I'm trying to orderby an object how do I do that and I have searched online before posting it here.

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.templates = {
        template_address: "../template/address.html",
        template_book: "../template/book.html",
        template_create: "../template/create.html" 
    };



<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="(name, path) in templates">{{name}}: {{path}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/abuhamzah/6fbpdm9m/

Comment: In what order are you trying to put them? They're already in order.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can't apply a filter to a plain object, [only to arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14789258/1945651).

What you can do is define a method in the controller to convert the object to an array:

```
$scope.templatesAry = function () {
    var ary = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.templates, function (val, key) {
        ary.push({key: key, val: val});
    });
    return ary;
};
```

and then filter that:

```
<li ng-repeat="prop in templatesAry() | orderBy:'-key'">
     {{prop.key}}: {{prop.val}}
</li>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/w6q47z37/1/)

Comment: i see that its working but my `ng-include` is not working even I tried something like this `<ng-include src="ary.val"></ng-include>`

Comment: @AbuHamzah Can you update your question to show the new code you tried?

Comment: I have replaced my code with what I have posted as an answer but thanks for your help 1+

Comment: getting console error: `10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!`

Comment: You should cache the result of the function somewhere to avoid the infinite digest error that @MikeCarson is getting.

Comment: I don't see much point in using angular.forEach... Using standard `for .. in` is actually shorter code:
`for (const key in $scope.templates) { ary.push({key: key, val: $scope.templates[key]}); }`

Comment: Do not use this solution, you will end up in an infinite digest loop. [See here for details.](https://code.angularjs.org/1.8.2/docs/error/$rootScope/infdig)

Answer (score 2):

so i think this would work and it also maintains the same object pointer,

```
app.filter('orderObjectBy', [function()  {
  return (filterObj, prop) => {

let arr = []
//below is the loadash function you can use for in also
_.forEach(filterObj, function(value, key)  {
  arr.push({
    key: key,
    value: value
  });
});

let sortedArr = _.sortBy(arr, val => val.value[prop]);

for (let variableKey in filterObj) {
  if (filterObj.hasOwnProperty(variableKey)) {
    delete filterObj[variableKey];
  }
}

for (let data of sortedArr) {
  filterObj[data.key] = data.value;
}


    return filterObj;

  }
}])
```

Answer (score -1):

YOU not need to Keep it as Object , include the Key inside data filed , and make it array , after you can Use it as  item.key ; and you can remove it with _.omit

filter = function(items){

filtered={};

_.mapObject(items,function(V,K){

```
V.key = K; // Include the key in the data; your can _.omit it after
```

if(V.name = 'test'){filtered[K]=V;};

});

return _.sortBy(filtered,'anyFieldSortCoudBeThe KEY it self'); //sortBy will return array sorted 
};

Answer (score -4):

Credit goes to ryeballar

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27466368/275390

Instead of using a key-value object, why not use an array? `ng-repeat` orders the iteration by the index of the iterated object/array.

[**FORKED DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/jFMAb7zok97YzTV6inAV?p=preview)

```
  $scope.templates = [
    'create.html',
    'book.html',
    'address.html'
  ];
```

Comment: You changed your own requirement and answered it. It may have solved your current issue but does not answer the question.