# ng-include how to make a orderBy to an object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I'm aware that Angular filters can only be applied to arrays, not objects

I'm attempting to include templates added dynamically using the following code. All seems to work well until you see the order

What I would like to have this order:

`Create
Book
Address`

here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FUVgZV38O7KvDB0P3S4I)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a key-value object, why not use an array? `ng-repeat` orders the iteration by the index of the iterated object/array.

[**FORKED DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/jFMAb7zok97YzTV6inAV?p=preview)

```
  $scope.templates = [
    'create.html',
    'book.html',
    'address.html'
  ];
```

Answer (score 1):

seems like angular will get `ng-include` by ordering the names according to their name,

so when you use

```
$scope.templates = 
{
  _address : 'address.html',
  _create : 'create.html',
  _book : 'book.html'
};
```

ordering `template` according to their names, then `_address comes first` `_book comes second` `_create comes third`

simple approach to solve

```
$scope.templates = 
{
  _a_create : 'create.html',
  _b_address : 'address.html',
  _c_book : 'book.html'
};
```

here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uOUZyDaBaJ0XYYhaWKnl?p=preview)

Comment: why didn't I think of this? arggg

Comment: yes i though of not using `ng-repeat` but wanted to see if there is a better solution then just not using `ng-repeat`

Comment: I think @ryeballar simple answer is better than this.