# AngularJS reverse ng:repeat Object order

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My program uploads an excel file and reads it out except in reverse order. It's an Array of Objects and I cant seem to get ng:repeat to spit out the objects in reverse order.

[image]

here is what the excel spread sheet looks like

[image]
here is the actual result

```
   <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <tbody>
            <tr ng:repeat="row in sheet.sheet">
                <td ng:repeat="cell in row | orderBy : sortingOrder : reverse" ng:bind="cell"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

here is a visual of the array of objects from the console

[image]

Comment: Show some code, at least the ng:repeat code.

Comment: The order by filter works with arrays only, here is a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27454658/398606). They suggest converting your `row` objects into an array. You might also take a look at [this blog post](http://justinklemm.com/angularjs-filter-ordering-objects-ngrepeat/) which has a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <tbody>
        <tr ng:repeat="row in sheet.sheet">
            <td ng:repeat="cell in row | orderBy : expression : reverse" ng:bind="cell"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

your expression can be anything from your scope object

Answer (score 0):

I actually found it easier to flip the direction of the entire table with css! Thank you everyone for your help!

```
#container { direction: rtl }
```

This was much easier than trying to reorder the objects into an array.