# How can i make dynamic ng-repeat using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Below I have added my data

```
[{
"name":"testapp",
"version":"2.0",
"description":"testapp",
"applicationenvironment":"angularjs"

}]
```

I want to make `ng-repeat` but I don't want to hard code any field (`name`, `version`, `description`, `applicationenvironment`)
How can I achieve this?

MY expectation :

IN TABLE it should come like this

[image]

Comment: you need two of them: one is for an array of objects (`ng-repeat="data in array"`), the other is for key and value pair of each object (`ng-repeat="(key,value) in data"`), then display it with `{{key}}` and `{{value}}`

Comment: can you add full code i am new to this pls help me to move forward

Comment: I just notices how you want it to be displayed, and it makes no sense for your table data to be an array. Simply change to be an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your array should be an object**. So your structure simplifies quite a lot. Just extract key and values from your object and loop over it for each row. Then display key and values in separate columns per row:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.table = [{
    "name": "testapp",
    "version": "2.0",
    "description": "testapp",
    "applicationenvironment": "angularjs"
  }]
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <table>

      <tr>
        <th>Key</th>
        <th>Value</th>
      </tr>

      <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in table[0]">
        <td>{{key}}</td>
        <td>{{value}}</td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how can i add orderBy : 'key'

Comment: @coco that makes no sense. Objects cannot be ordered. You would need to somehow [turn them into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27454730/8495123) perhaps (in controller)

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't recommend you to have this strucuture, you can do something like this:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('appController', function () {
    this.data = {
        "name":"testapp",
        "version":"2.0",
        "description":"testapp",
        "applicationenvironment":"angularjs"
    };
});
```

And your HTML would be something like this:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="appController as vm">
    <ul>
         <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in vm.data"> {{ key }} : {{ value }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If you still need to have the data inside an array as you've wrote in the question, you would have to iterate over both the array and the object.

Comment: how can i add orderBy : 'key'

Answer (score 0):

Now since your data source is an array, you need to do two nested ng-repeats

```js
let app = angular.module("table",[]);
    app.controller("tableCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope){

    $scope.data = [{
    "name":"testapp",
    "version":"2.0",
    "description":"testapp",
    "applicationenvironment":"angularjs"
    },
    {
    "name":"testapp 2",
    "version":"2.1",
    "description":"testapp 2",
    "applicationenvironment":"angularjs"
    }];
    }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="table" ng-controller="tableCtrl">
    <table ng-repeat="row in data">
     <tr><td>Key</td><td>Value</td></tr>
     <tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in row">
       <td>{{key}}</td><td>{{value}}</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Now if you do this, your data structure should yield the wanted result

Answer (score -1):

You need to loop twice: Once through each the entire array of objects to access each object, and then inside each object to access individual key-value pairs.

I have posted the code below:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('Controller1', function () {
    this.data = {
        "name":"testapp",
        "version":"2.0",
        "description":"testapp",
        "applicationenvironment":"angularjs"
    };
});

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Controller1 as c1">
    <table>

    <tr>
        <th>Key</th>
        <th>Value</th>
    </tr>

    <tr ng-repeat="c in c1.data">
       <table>
         <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in c">
         <td> {{ key }} </td>
         <td> {{ value }} </td>
         </tr>
       </table>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```