# angular filtered dropdown model not updating

Tags: angularjs, filter

I'm trying to update a filtered dropdowns(combobox) model on click of a button. The model value is changing but dropdown still shows an empty selected option. If I remove the filter everything works as it should (without filtering of course).

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/a48JSEiiATrkcQKxfJjx?p=preview

JS:

```
$scope.tasks = [
    {name:'Task1', taskid: 1, custid: 2},
    {name:'Task2', taskid: 2, custid: 2},
    {name:'Task3', taskid: 3, custid: 3}
    ];

  $scope.myinfo = {};
  $scope.updateinfo = {name:'Cust Name', custid: 3, taskid: 3};

  $scope.setMyinfo = function(){
    $scope.myinfo = $scope.updateinfo;
  };
});

app.filter('taskFilter', function() {
  return function(input, criteria) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if(input[i].custid == criteria || input[i].custid === undefined){
            result.push(input[i]);
        }
    }
    return result;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<button ng-click="setMyinfo()">Button</button>
    <br> <br>
    Filtered:
    <select ng-model="myinfo.taskid">
      <option>---</option>
      <option ng-repeat="task in tasks | taskFilter:myinfo.custid" value="{{task.taskid}}">{{task.name}}</option>
    </select>

    Unfiltered:
    <select ng-model="myinfo.taskid">
      <option>---</option>
      <option ng-repeat="task in tasks" value="{{task.taskid}}">{{task.name}}</option>
    </select>

  <br><br>
  Value: {{myinfo.taskid}}
```

Thanks you for helping!

Answer (score 0):

pre-filter the list by key and value:

```
<div ng-repeat="(k,v) in filterCustId(tasks)">
    {{k}} {{v.pos}}
</div>
```

And on the Controller:

```
$scope.filterCustId = function(items) {
    var result = {};
    angular.forEach(items, function(value, key) {
        if (!value.hasOwnProperty('custid')) {
            result[key] = value;
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

From: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14789258/4668696

Comment: is it best to filter in the controller or in the in the view?

Comment: filter in the controller. you should not have any logic in the view @gerl

Comment: you mean isSelected? Then yes. but still it is always an opinion and it is possible in the view. http://toddmotto.com/everything-about-custom-filters-in-angular-js/

Answer (score 0):

Please update code following line

```
if(input[i].custid == criteria || input[i].custid === undefined){
```

by

```
 if(input[i].custid == criteria || input[i].custid === undefined || criteria == undefined){
```