# Filter object key not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, object

**Note**: I already read and try all answers inside [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788652/how-to-filter-key-value-with-ng-repeat-in-angularjs). Unfortunately, it's not working for me and I got no luck.

I create a simple Angular app to play around with [CurrencyLayer API](https://currencylayer.com/documentation). My app is working great but only 1 thing didn't work.

I couldn't filter the currency key. What I want is, when user type in their currency inside the search box, the currency is filtered out in the `ul` div.

`filter:{key:searchCurrency}` is not working for me.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular Currency Converter</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    input {
        outline: none;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
        -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
        box-shadow: none !important;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column-md-12">
                <p>Base currency: {{sourceCurrency}}</p>

                <label>Amount</label>
                <input type="number" ng-model="amount" class="form-control" /><br/>

                <label>Search</label>
                <input ng-model="searchCurrency" class="form-control" placeholder="Search currency"/><br/>
                <pre>searchCurrency: {{searchCurrency}}</pre>

                <p>{{amount}} {{sourceCurrency}} is equavalent to:</p>

                <ul ng-repeat="(key, quote) in quotes | filter:{key:searchCurrency}">
                    <!--
                    key.slice(3,6) is to remove USD from all result strings like USDAED -> AED
                    quote * amount will give calculated result based on input user give
                    number : 2 to give the result nice looking 2 decimal places
                    -->
                    <li>{{key.slice(3,6)}}: {{quote * amount | number : 2}}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        // init the amount to 1 (USD 1.00)
        $scope.amount = 1;

        $http.get("http://apilayer.net/api/live?access_key=XXX&format=1")
            .success(function(response) {
                // get currency exchange data
                $scope.quotes = response.quotes;
                // get source currency (USD)
                $scope.sourceCurrency = response.source;
            });

    })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Sample JSON data like inside this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1ba5d59992c9a4aab0d4).

[Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/6zHo5ppyC9iohorqgkdj/preview)

How to make the search filter works?

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788652/how-to-filter-key-value-with-ng-repeat-in-angularjs

Comment: Very well written question, unfortunately there are numerous duplicates.

Comment: I already read and try all answers inside this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788652/how-to-filter-key-value-with-ng-repeat-in-angularjs). 

Unfortunately, it's not working for me and I got no luck.

Comment: Done. I use `ng-show="([key] | filter:searchCurrency).length > 0"`. 

It's now up and running here https://github.com/zulhfreelancer/angularjs-currency-converter