# How to exclude a specific value in ng-options in angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I am new to **Angular**. I want to have a drop down with ng-options.

I have a end point which is returning the back end data. **For example** my back end data has 1, 2 , 3 ,4, 5. While displaying with the ng-options I don't want to display the first value.

(i.e I want in my drop down box only 2,3,4,5)

**I have the following code:**

```
<select class="form-control" ng-options="num as num for num in numbers id="no_num" ng-model="no.number" required> </select>
```

Comment: remove it from the controller code

Comment: Thanks. But is it possible to do it using angular filter

Comment: yes possible as well

Comment: I have this piece of code.<select class="form-control" ng-options="num as num for num in numbers   id="no_numbers" ng-model="no.numbers" required>
     </select>

Comment: How to modify this to exclude a specific value. Thanks!!

Comment: even though you do through a filter you need to write some logic in controller. is that fine?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want to implement a filter option in your backend, you think you're probably looking for the [filter called filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).

There's [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33290828/how-to-filter-a-select-with-ng-options-in-angular) that I believe answers this exact question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to display the first value of `list :[1, 2 , 3 ,4, 5]`. I would suggest to use `ng-repeat` in option tag and prevent first value 1 with `ng-if` :

**In controller:**

```
$scope.numbers=[1, 2 , 3 ,4, 5];
```

**In HTML:**

```
<select ng-model="value">
   <option ng-repeat="number in numbers" value="number" ng-if="number!=1">{{number}}</option>
</select>
```

You can also use $first to prevent first value like this:

```
<select ng-model="value">
   <option ng-repeat="number in numbers" value="number" ng-if="!$first">{{number}}</option>
</select>
```