# AngularJS limiting table size doesn't work

Tags: angularjs

I have a table and I am trying to limit the size of that table to 5. Here is what i have so far.

```
 <tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in cla|limitTo:5">
     <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">{{ key}}</td>
     <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">{{ value | number:2}}</td>                         
 </tr>
```

And this workss....

```
<tr ng-repeat="prof in profstats | limitTo:3 " ng-click="selectedProf(key)">
    <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">{{ prof.name}}</td>
    <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">{{ prof.avgGrade}}</td>
</tr>
```

Does this issue have to do with key, value maybe?

Comment: could you show your controller.js?

Comment: @infaustus Why would controller cause this problem?

Comment: Maybe it is a typo in controller.js Just see that in the first example there is no space betwen filter and collection, `<tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in cla|limitTo:5">` and should be `<tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in cla | limitTo:5">`

Comment: @infaustus still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work, because `limitTo` is expecting an `array` and `cla` is an `object`

Comment: is there a fix for this?

Comment: Make cla have only properties you want to loop or you need to create your own filter. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788652/how-to-filter-key-value-with-ng-repeat-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a custom filter like so:

```
app.filter('objectLimitTo', function() {
    return function(obj, limit) {
        var result = {};

        var curr = 0;

        for (var key in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                result[key] = obj[key];

                if (++curr===limit) break;
            }
        }

        return result;
    };
});
```

And template:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in (cla|objectLimitTo:5)">
    <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">{{ key}}</td>
    <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">{{ value | number:2}}</td>                         
</tr>
```