# Using filter to sort $scope object in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, sorting, angular-filters

I need to sort a `$scope` object in `ng-repeat` based on value. I am able to acheive the sorting by converting it into `array` through custom filter but either key or value only can be pushed into the `array`. I needed both key and value to show it in the UI:

```
$scope.list = {
    test:58uy43: "test:one", 
    test:24ht76: "test:two", 
    test:26df90: "test:three", 
    test:39fg67: "test:four", 
    test:18ds65: "test:five"
}

<div ng-repeat="(key,value) in list">{{key}} : {{value}}</div>
```

Please help me out on this

Comment: You'd better have an array of objects I think

Comment: You might find this usefull: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788652/how-to-filter-key-value-with-ng-repeat-in-angularjs

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the cleanest way would be to define a function in your controller that returns the sorted list.

```
$scope.getListSorted = function() {
    $scope.list.sort(function(a, b) { return /*comparison*/; });
};
```

For numeric values *comparison* should be `a.attr - b.attr` if you want to sort ascending.
For string values *comparison* should be `a.attr.localeCompare(b.attr)`.

Then you can use it in the view

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,value) in getListSorted()">{{key}} : {{value}}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

...ng-repeat="o in data | filter: filter | orderBy:sortPredicate:sortReverse"...

where 'filter' is the value you'd like to search on (filter), 'sortPredicate' is a column name which you'd like to order by and 'sortReverse' is a boolean indicating the order of records.