# Sort an object in angularjs ng-repeat directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object

```
Object {1: "CMAR0002", 2: "CMAR0003", 4: "CMAR0001"}
```

I am using this object in ng-repeat directive but i want to sort it by values. But the problem is that angular orderBy filter requires array of objects. But i have only pretty simple object here ;)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter (key, value) with ng-repeat in AngularJs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788652/how-to-filter-key-value-with-ng-repeat-in-angularjs)

Comment: @isherwood It is not duplicate they have object of objects but i have a plain simple object

Answer (score 1):

By [Angular ng-repeat documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat):

> It is possible to get ngRepeat to iterate over the properties...
>
> However, there are a limitations compared to array iteration, like "The built-in filters **orderBy** and **filter** do not work with objects, and will throw if used with one"

If you are hitting any of these limitations, the recommended workaround is to convert your object into an array that is sorted into the order that you prefer before providing it to `ngRepeat`. You could do this with a filter such as [toArrayFilter](http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-toArrayFilter) or implement a $watch on the object yourself.

Anyway, you can try to implement you own filter for this, but it will be pretty ugly and it will require much effort (probably for nothing).

Hope, it will help you!

Comment: I tried with toArrayFilter, as my object values are not object so i needed to add "toArray:false" in ng-repeat but it throughs an error "TypeError: Object.values is not a function"  thttp://plnkr.co/edit/atENz4yKb8e6wrgioy3g?p=preview

Comment: Correct. In this example it has an old version of js.file. If you take a look on the [current version of toArrayFilter](https://github.com/petebacondarwin/angular-toArrayFilter/blob/master/toArrayFilter.js) and try to use it - it works [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HVnIQGH21JkxJqSCDzLs?p=preview)

Answer (score -1):

Do this:

```
<li ng-repeat="(key, value) in Object | orderBy: key">
    {{ key }} - {{ value }}
</li>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oo4cb9xf/1/