# ng-repeat for an array inside an array

Tags: html, arrays, angularjs, mongodb, filter

I want to filter a table based on a (single) checkbox. The problem is that I don't know how to compare the checkbox value to one value in a array inside the database. I have tried this, but it don't work:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="myMaster" ng-true-value="{{vm.user.master}}" ng-false-value='' /> {{vm.user.master}}</label>

<tr ng-repeat="course in vm.courses |filter:search| limitTo: 50">
      <span ng-repeat="master in course.master | filter:myMaster">
                <td >{{course.courseName}}</td>....
```

`vm.courses.master` do have an array with different master values where one is `vm.user.master`. Anybody know how to solve this?

EDIT: This is vm.courses: [image: vm.courses]
This is vm.user: [image]

EDIT2: This is the structure of my controller: [[Controller][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hw8PP.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hw8PP.png)

Comment: Can you print what's inside vm.courses and inside vm.user?

Comment: Absolutely! edited the question @Juanín

Comment: I'm not really sure what you achieve. For what I see, you are trying to print one or more courses that have the user master, and it can be in either of the masters attributes (logistic, quality, production, etc). Am I right?

Comment: I think you understood it right. If the checkbox is checked I want to print only the courses that have the same master as the user have. A user can only have one master but a course can have several (or none).@Juanín

Comment: I think the problem might be that you put a span inside a tr. Can you try using only divs?

Comment: Also please check if you can see myMaster inside the first ng-repeat (sometimes angularjs has problems with scopes)

Comment: Did not work :/ @Juanín

Comment: :/ And can you put {{myMaster}} inside the tr?

Comment: I tried printing myMaster like this {{myMaster}} but it didn't show, neither in the ng-repeat or directly under the input  @Juanín

Comment: Try initializing it (on the controller) as $scope.myMaster = {} and on the ng-model use myMaster.value

Comment: I think ng-repeat has an enclosed scope and variables that are not objects are not reachable inside that scope. The same happens with ng-if.

Comment: I've updated my answer, it should work now

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34190042/5126411

Comment: having a span directly inside a tr is not valid html. Depending on the browser it might result in wierd results (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr)

Comment: moreover. if the input is inside the table tag, it should be moved outside

Comment: Tried doning this both in controller and also with ng-init, but didn't work :/ @Juanín

Comment: hmmm I ran out of ideas :S but I think you should try to figure out why you cannot access the scope and then after figuring that out format the html with the right tags (following the answer given by @StianStandahl).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<span ng-repeat="(key,value) in course.master" ng-show="value==myMaster">
```

Comment: This limits the filter to only logistics and I want it to work overall. I have some more users and they may have different master

Comment: If your field course.master contains a dictionary with masters you should create your own filter and check whether myMaster contains in this dictionary

Answer (score 0):

have you tried moving the loop out to a tbody tag and the inner loop to tr? like so:

```
...
<tbody ng-repeat="course in vm.courses |filter:search| limitTo: 50">
  <tr ng-repeat="master in course.master | filter:myMaster">
    <td>{{course.courseName}}</td>
...
```

[A table can have zero or more tbody tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table)

if you want to filter on specific variables in an object you can also create your own [custom comparer](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) that does this.

Comment: Tried this now, this made the hole table disappear

Comment: do you have a jsFiddle that i can do this in?

Comment: I haven't done one before, but I can try doning one!

Comment: I don't know wish values I should put in the controller since my controller look a bit different. I have printed screen how it look and maybe you know better

Comment: instead of printscreen, copy paste the two objects as json. run JSON.stringify([object]) on the object

Comment: the two printscreen of the object structure as json should suffice

Comment: Im sorry if i'm a little bad at this but I don't understand how to do that

Comment: I found the error I got when I did your suggestion: "angular.js:12477 Error: [filter:notarray]"

Comment: @sacan - i've simplified your example and done something here that you can check out https://jsfiddle.net/aq676/367/ . tell me if it helps then i'll add it to the answer

Comment: Thank you! A new problem seems to be that if you have two ng-repeat the courses that have mutable masters will appear several times in the table :/