# 'filter' filter in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an array of objects and I want to extract the value when key is passes in 'filter' filter. Below is the controller code snippet I have tried, but the type of response I get is undefined. Please help me in finding where am I going wrong.

```
var states =  [{"HIMACHAL PRADESH":"HP"},{"JAMMU AND KASHMIR":"JK"},{"JHARKHAND":"JH"},{"KARNATAKA":"KA"},{"KERALA":"KL"},{"MADHYA PRADESH":"MP"},{"MAHARASHTRA":"MH"},{"ORISSA":"OR"}]
var str = "ORISSA";
var abbr = $filter('filter')(states, {key: str}, true).value;
console.log ("ABBR:"+abbr);
```

P.S. I have injected $filter in the controller

Comment: pls show your filter

Comment: @Prastheesh I am using 'filter' filter provided by AngularJS

Comment: You need to create a custom filter for that. Check the answers for this question. It is a similar problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788652/how-to-filter-key-value-with-ng-repeat-in-angularjs/34190042

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.keys` and `find`

```
var matchedState = states.find( s => Object.keys( s )[0] == str );
var abbr = matchedState ? matchedState[str] : ""
```

**Demo**

```js
var states = [{
  "HIMACHAL PRADESH": "HP"
}, {
  "JAMMU AND KASHMIR": "JK"
}, {
  "JHARKHAND": "JH"
}, {
  "KARNATAKA": "KA"
}, {
  "KERALA": "KL"
}, {
  "MADHYA PRADESH": "MP"
}, {
  "MAHARASHTRA": "MH"
}, {
  "ORISSA": "OR"
}]
var str = "ORISSA";
var matchedState = states.find(s => Object.keys(s)[0] == str);
var abbr = matchedState ? matchedState[str] : ""
console.log(abbr);
```

Comment: Thanks Gurvinder.  The solution is working fine. Wanted to know if it can be done with filter in AngularJs

Comment: Sorry, I am not aware how to use filter in AngularJS to solve your problem. Vanilla JS solutions works for me, so never needed another library for such trivial tasks :)